# Doing a DFS on a neo4j graph

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I have a database with the following structure.
[image]

The property node is of the type

```
 create (A:Property {value:"abc"})
```

How to do a dfs so that it will be able to print all the values in the graph.In the order A->B->E->F->C->G->H->D->I->J

The relationship r is in the downward direction(single direction) with no properties.I have tried this [link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) but looks complex to me.

Is there an easier way to do a simple dfc on an already existing Neo4j database

Answer (score 3):

The link you linked to is very verbose to cover all the different things you can do with Neo4j's powerful Traversal API.

I think all you have to do is this:

```
TraversalDescription traversalDescription = graphDb.traversalDescription()
            .depthFirst()
            .relationships(YourRelationShipTypeR, Direction.OUTGOING);

    Node a = ... // however you find your node A

    try(ResourceIterator<Node> nodes =traversalDescription.traverse(a)
                                                       .nodes()
                                                       .iterator()){
        while(nodes.hasNext()){
            Node n = nodes.next();
            //or whatever property name you use to get your names for nodes
            System.out.print(n.getProperty("id") + "->");
        }

    }
```

Should print `A->B->E->F->C->G->H->D->I->J->`

You can make the print statement smarter by not appending the arrow at the last node but I'll leave that up to you

**EDIT**

After trying the code myself I got a depth first search but the iterator order was out of order.  It seemed it arbitrarily picked which child node to walk first.  So I got output like `A->D->J->I->C->H->G->B->F->E->`.

So you have to sort the returned Paths of the `TraversalDescription` which has a `sort(Comparator<Path> )` method.

To match the traversal you want, I sorted the paths by the node property that gives the node its name, which I called "id".  Here's my updated traversal code:

```
 TraversalDescription traversalDescription = graphDb.traversalDescription()
            .depthFirst()
            .sort(new PathComparatorByName())
            .relationships(YourRelationShipTypeR, Direction.OUTGOING);
```

Where PathComparatorByName is a comparator I wrote that sorts Paths based on the nodes traversed in the path lexigraphically sorted by name:

```
private class PathComparatorByName implements Comparator<Path>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Path o1, Path o2) {
        Iterator<Node> iter1 = o1.nodes().iterator();
        Iterator<Node> iter2 = o2.nodes().iterator();


        while(iter1.hasNext()){
            if(!iter2.hasNext()){
                //return shorter path?
                return 1;
            }

            Node n1 = iter1.next();
            Node n2 = iter2.next();
            int nodeCmp = compareByNodeName(n1, n2);
            if(nodeCmp !=0){
                return nodeCmp;
            }

        }
        if(iter2.hasNext()){
            //return shorter path?
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int compareByNodeName(Node node1, Node node2) {
        String name1 = (String)node1.getProperty("id");

         String name2 = (String)node2.getProperty("id");

        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }

}
```

Rerunning it now with the comparator will output:

```
A->B->E->F->C->G->H->D->I->J->
```

Comment: Updated code to sort the traversal paths to match user desired output